# System.ArgumentException: 'Process with an Id of <ProcessID> is not running.' in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

currently my application is on .net framework 4.8 using this I need to  run a .exe file which is in .net 6.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process newProcess = null;
        try
        {
            // create application
            ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "<path of the .exe file>",
                Arguments = arguments,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetTempPath()
            };


newProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = procInfo,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };

 // now start the process
            newProcess.Start();
            newProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
            started = true;
```

But after last line when I check this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(newProcess.Id)
```

i am getting an exception[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
            newProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
```

Wrap this in a try/catch. The process died trying to start.

Now then; if the process dies so early `newProcess.ExitCode` will be a `HRESULT` of the failure to start the process (or rarely an NT error code).

If it's an unexpected zero and the process didn't do anything, blame antivirus.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(newProcess.Id)
```

But whyyyyy? Looks like you want `newProcess.Refresh()`.

Comment: actually this Line System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(newProcess.Id) i am using in immediate window to see if the process is running or not .

Comment: @Adityadalai: Doesn't matter. You need the exit code to make progress.

Comment: but the samething is working when I tried it for a .net framemework 4.8 .exe file , but after migrate that console app it into .net 6  it failes , is it a compatable issue ?

Comment: @Adityadalai: No. It's a you messed something up issue without a whole lot of useful details.